# rewrite rules hierarchical

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I want that my WordPress follow this rules:

1. `/productes/` a page with all products
2. `/productes/[category]/` a taxonomy-page with all products of the category
3. `/productes/[category]/[subcategory]/` a taxonomy-page with all products of the category (the same as 2)
4. `/[productes]/[category]/[product]/` a `single-productes.php` that will show the category product
5. `/[productes]/[category]/[subcategory]/[product]/` a `single-productes.php` that will show the subcategory product (same as 4)

`[category]/[subcategory]` is an hierarchical taxonomy is equivalent to `%categories_productes%`

I have these two rules:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'tatanet_rewrite_rules');
function tatanet_rewrite_rules($rules) {
  $newRules  = array();
  $newRules['(.+)/?$']                                  = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]';
  $newRules['productes/(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$']     = 'index.php?productes=$matches[3]';
  return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

I have registered this taxonomy:

```
$labels = array(
'name'                          => 'Categories',
'singular_name'                 => 'Categoria',
'search_items'                  => 'Buscar Categories',
'all_items'                     => 'Totes les Categories',
'parent_item'                   => 'Categoria superior',
'edit_item'                     => 'Editar Categoria',
'update_item'                   => 'Actualitzar Categoria',
'add_new_item'                  => 'Afegir nova Categoria',
'new_item_name'                 => 'Nova Categoria',
'separate_items_with_commas'    => 'Separar Categories amb comes',
'add_or_remove_items'           => 'Afegir o treure Categoria',
);
$args = array(
'label'                         => 'Categories',
'labels'                        => $labels,
'public'                        => true,
'hierarchical'                  => true,
'show_ui'                       => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
'query_var'                     => true,
'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
'rewrite'                       => array( 'slug' => 'productes', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true )
);
register_taxonomy( 'categories_productes', 'productes', $args );
```

I have registered this post type:

```
$labels = array(
  'name' => _x('Productes', 'post type general name'),
  'singular_name' => _x('Producte', 'post type singular name'),
  'add_new' => _x('Afegir nou', 'productes'),
  'add_new_item' => __('Afegir nou producte'),
  'edit_item' => __('Editar producte'),
  'new_item' => __('Nou producte'),
  'all_items' => __('Tots els productes'),
  'view_item' => __('Veure producte'),
  'search_items' => __('Cercar productes'),
  'not_found' =>  __('No s\'han trobat productes'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('No s\'han trobat productes a la Paperera'), 
  'parent_item_colon' => '',
  'menu_name' => 'Productes'
);
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'show_in_menu' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => 'productes', 
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => -4,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'productes/%categories_productes%', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
  'supports' => array( 'title' )
); 
register_post_type( 'productes', $args );
}
```

This is the URL and the page load result:

1. `/productes/`                                      OK => load the page products that runs `template-productes.php`
2. `/productes/[category]/`                            OK => load `taxonomy-categories_productes.php`
3. `/productes/[category]/[subcategory]/`              ?? => 404 error not found
4. `/[productes]/[category]/[product]/`                OK => load `single-productes.php` of the `[product]`
5. `/[productes]/[category]/[subcategory]/[product]/`  OK => load `single-productes.php` of the `[product]`

Why the 3 point isn't working?

I have got a page named productes (maybe it is causing the conflict?)

I have got this permalink rewriter of the posts:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'categories_productes_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'categories_productes_permalink', 10, 3);

function categories_productes_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
  if (strpos($permalink, '%categories_productes%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if (!$post) return $permalink;
  // get taxonomy terms
  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'categories_productes');  
  if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
  else $taxonomy_slug = 'uncategorized';
  return str_replace('%categories_productes%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to my problem.
Now I have to also keep in mind that the products within a category can be paged.
Then there is a new rule for paged categories... Please someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

When Wordpress parses the incoming requests, it has no way of differentiating between what might be a product and what might be a subcategory. One will take precedence - it will either always look for a matching subcategory or it will always look for a matching product, depending on the order in which it processes the rules.

Comment: Then is there a way to change the order?
Or a way to solve this?

Comment: If you change the order you're just swapping precedence, you still won't get both to co-exist. the bottom line is each rule must have uniqueness baked in for WordPress to differentiate.